# How to use improved Euler's method formula to solve an IVP involving population growth?

Tags: differential-equations

Hi so I have a problem from my differential equations class that I am having difficulty solving with the improved Euler's method:

The logistic equation for the population (in thousands) of a certain species is given by `dP/dt = 2P-2P^2`. With t being time variable in years

Given P(0) = .5, with step size h = .2 (so .2 of t), find population at 1 year. 
I used the normal Euler's method and got 634 but am not sure how to implement the modified Euler's method on the given differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

The improved Euler method or explicit midpoint method has two stages

- Stage one is an Euler step with half the step size
- Stage two is the full step with the slope from the point from step one.

So if `dP/dt = Q(P)` then

```
k1 = Q(P0)
k2 = Q(P0 + h/2 * k1)
P1 = P0 + h * k2
```

or

```
Phalf = P0+h/2*Q(P0)
P1 = P0 + h*Q(Phalf)
```